# Possible to Send Email from Exchange Account via Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, email, command-line, terminal, exchange-server

I would like to send an email from my Exchange email account via Mac Terminal. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing so? I'm running OS X 10.10.5 and have my email set up on Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to send email from your Outlook client for whatever reason, you'll need your user and pass in base64 handy to cut/past into the terminal.  Go here for an example:  [How to test SMTP Auth using telnet](https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/test-smtp-auth-telnet)

This comes with caveats.  This is not SSL, so you're using SMTPS or StartTLS you'll need to do this all via OpenSSL s_client like this:  [Test SSL SMTP from command line](http://mac-blog.org.ua/test-ssl-smtp/)

I've used these in the past and they work.  If it doesn't work, you'll need to find out what SMTP connection strings are allowed.  For clients I always ran SMTP Client Submission which listens on 587 and required STARTTLS prior to Auth.  SMTPS on 465 was disabled...Lemme know if this works.

-Chase